# Split the date of same column in multiple rows till the next date value is specified - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table

```
+------+------------+-----+
| Code |    date    | qty |
+------+------------+-----+
|    1 | 06-07-2017 |  44 |
|    1 | 08-07-2017 |  45 |
|    2 | 07-07-2017 |  32 |
|    2 | 09-07-2017 |  33 |
+------+------------+-----+
```

and I want to display it this way

```
+------+------------+-----+
| Code |    date    | qty |
+------+------------+-----+
|    1 | 06-07-2017 |  44 |
|    1 | 07-07-2017 |  44 |
|    1 | 08-07-2017 |  45 |
|    2 | 07-07-2017 |  32 |
|    2 | 08-07-2017 |  32 |
|    2 | 09-07-2017 |  33 |
+------+------------+-----+
```

I want to split the date of same 'Code' and keep the same value for 'qty' till the next date of same 'Code'.

Comment: Where is your code? In which programming language?

Comment: It's a database table. In SQL Server I'm using it.

Comment: You will have only two records for each code in input/

Comment: @KannanKandasamy No. It will vary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a *calendar* table and `Outer Apply`

```
;WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT Min([date]) AS st, 
                Max([date]) ed, 
                code 
         FROM   Yourtable 
         GROUP  BY code 
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT Dateadd(dd, 1, st) AS st, 
                ed, 
                code 
         FROM   cte 
         WHERE  Dateadd(dd, 1, st) <= ed) 
SELECT c.code, 
       [date]=c.st, 
       qty 
FROM   cte c 
       OUTER apply (SELECT TOP 1 qty 
                    FROM   Yourtable a 
                    WHERE  a.code = c.code 
                           AND c.st >= a.[date] 
                    ORDER  BY [date] DESC) oa 
ORDER  BY c.code,st
```

**Note :** For the sake of completeness I have used `Recursive CTE` to generate the dates you can always create a physical calendar table in your database and use it.

- [**Live Demo**](http://rextester.com/AQOO7401)

Comment: Would you mind posting a solution that uses a calendar table? I'm curious now.